# How to clear this equation?

Tags: inequality, nonlinear-optimization

In a homework i got this exercise:

To clean a work of art you have to use a $CO_2$ laser with pulse duration of $\Delta t$. The temperature reached at the point of impact follows the law.

$T = 300 + 60 \Delta t e^{\frac{5\Delta t}{3}}$

If T > 400 the work of art gets burned. To clean it is needed a total time of 5 seconds. For each pulse with radiation there is an equal await with no radiation.

$a)$ Get the non-linear equation needed to find a value for the duration of each pulse $\Delta t$. The work of art has to be cleaned without burning with the less possible amount of pulses.

$b)$ Write the equation in the form $f(\Delta t)$ and graph the function $f$ in an interval suited for the problem solution.

I tried to clear the equation with no success. Because always get something in the form $xe^{\frac{5x}{3}} \leq \frac{10}{6}$ (x being $\Delta t$). And applying logarithms gives me something alike.

I think after clearing the equation I have to minimize it in order to get small value of $\Delta t$, but am not sure.

Help please. And thanks in advance.

Comment: has art ever been burned like this?

Comment: you want to clear the equation of what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I properly understand, you want to find the larget $x$ such that $$x\,e^{5x/3} \leq \frac{10}{6}$$ holds.

Sooner or later, you will learn that the equation has analytical roots in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). $$x\,e^{5x/3}= \frac{10}{6} \implies \frac{5x}{3} \,e^{5x/3}= \frac{25}{9} \implies x=\frac{3}{5} W\left(\frac{25}{9}\right)\approx 0.606513$$ If you do not want to use Lambert function, consider that you need the zero of $$f(x)=x\,e^{5x/3}- \frac{10}{6} $$ $$f'(x)=\frac{1}{3} e^{5 x/3} (5 x+3)$$ $$f''(x)=\frac{5}{9} e^{5 x/3} (5 x+6)$$The first and second derivatives are always positive since $x>0$ and you can safely use Newton method starting at $x_0=0$.

The method will generate the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.000000 \\
 1 & 1.666667 \\
 2 & 1.252921 \\
 3 & 0.914082 \\
 4 & 0.695801 \\
 5 & 0.615626 \\
 6 & 0.606616 \\
 7 & 0.606513
\end{array}
\right)$$

For sure, it would better to start iterating at $x_0=1$ since at this point $f(x)\times f''(x) >0$ (Darboux theorem) which would make 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 1.000000\\
 1 & 0.743047 \\
 2 & 0.626905 \\
 3 & 0.607021 \\
 4 & 0.606513
\end{array}
\right)$$ Since $f(x)$ is an increasing function, you then must have $x < 0.61$.

**Edit**

With this specific problem, there is something which is amazing if you notice that $\frac{25}9\approx e$. Built around $x=e$, the simplest Pade approximant is $$W(x)=\frac{\frac{7 (x-e)}{8 e}+1}{\frac{3 (x-e)}{8 e}+1}$$ giving $$W\left(\frac{25}{9}\right)\approx \frac{175+9 e}{75+45 e}\implies x=\frac 35 \times \frac{175+9 e}{75+45 e}\approx 0.606513$$.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clean the object with as a minimum number of pulses the duration of a pulse should be as long as possible. The temperature of the pulse increases with the duration of the pulse. So how long does it take until the critical temperature of 400 is reached? To find ou the time you have to solve the equation

$$300 + 60 \Delta t e^{\frac{5\Delta t}{3}}=400$$
This equation can be transformed to

$$  \Delta t e^{\frac{5\Delta t}{3}}=\frac{5}{3}$$

The unknown variable is $\Delta t$. 
This is the equation you already derived.
Such equations can be solved numerically using algorithms like newton's method.
Claude Leibovici already calculated an approximation $\Delta t \approx 0.6065$ to the solution in his [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2319260/11206).

The total time the laser has to be applied is $5$ seconds, so you need

$$\frac{5}{0.6} \approx 8.3$$ pulses. We need only a rough estimation for $\Delta t$ because the number of pulses must be an integer so we have to round that number up to $9$.

**Annotation:**

Because the number of pulses is $9$ and not $8.3$ we can reduce the duration of each pulse to $$\frac{5}{9}\approx 0.56$$ and then the maximum temperature of a pulse can be reduced to

$$300+60\cdot0.56\cdot e^{0.56\cdot 5/3}\approx 385.4$$